# Create a computed bool using relationship field Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, components

I'm trying figure out how my computed property identify if my relationship was set.

```
Project = Model.extend({
participantes: hasMany('author')
...
```

I need change my css based if has a author.

```
{{my-component project=project}}
//---------- my-component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['hasParticipante'],
  hasParticipante = Ember.computed('project.participantes', function(){
  //the code I need gonna here
})});
```

Comment: Arrow functions aren't short-hand for regular functions, they change the `this` binding. You can't pass an arrow function to `Ember.computed`.

Comment: You are right. I'm not replicate my real code.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably not work since a relationship is always a `PromiseArray` or `PromiseObject`. Probably you can check on the `content`:

```
Ember.computed.bool('author.content')
```

Your component seems completely wrong:

- You can't use `=` in Object creation.
- `Ember.get` needs two parameters. The context and the property, like `get(this, 'post')`.
- You should not use arrow functions for computed properties since you have no access to the object then.

But you don't need that line at all. Just do `classNameBindings: ['hasAuthor']`

Comment: Thank you your answer. I resolved changing my domain models ( currently my domain has  project - participants - client ) project - client and just add simple ember observe. `Ember.computed('project.clients', function(){ return clients.contain(client); }`